# Displaced SSD drives benchmark results

Tags: ssd, benchmarking, nvme

I have these two ssd drives:

SATA3 Samsung SSD 850 PRO 128 GB

NVME Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 240 GB with PCIExpress adapter

It seems the benchmark results are displaced. As you know the sata3 model never can to reach shown speed (1720 MB/s on Read and 2069 MB/s on Write).

and also for lower speed of nvme drive (417 MB/s on Read and 340 MB/s on Write) that must belong to sata3 drive normally.

Samsung Magician and Crystal DIskMArk, both are in the same wrong.

any idea?

[Samsung Magician result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av9ca.jpg)

[CrystalDiskMark 7 result for 850 pro sata3 drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtUVw.jpg)

[CrystalDiskMark 7 result for 970 evo plus nvme drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YDPU.jpg)